# WCF service issue in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have hosted WCF service in my system and created local IIS using IIS manager, I have set all settings like firewall and IP address and also enable HTTP activation and IIS, when I debug WCF service it give records accordingly.
I have added service reference in windows phone application using my development computer IP address. Two days before when I run the windows phone application in emulator, it ran classicly,since two days it is returning error :

```
"System.Servicemodel.Communication Exception".
```

Stuck here for last two days, please give me a way.Thnx!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Sajeetharan I checked that link, set all things correctly, still it is giving error.Thnx for ur quick rsponse.